# Как на linux'e создать виртуальный сетевой интерфейс и весь трафик с него перенаправить на socks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, socks5

Как на linux'e создать виртуальный сетевой интерфейс и весь трафик с него перенаправить на socks (127.0.0.1:6666 например)

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании "виртуальный сетевой интерфейс"? В идеале с примерами. Если Вам просто нужно открыть порт для прослушивания, это можно сделать с помощью утилиты `netcat`.

Comment: сетевой интерфейс нужен для `VirtualBox`

Comment: Не уверен что Вам оно надо, потому что вообще не понимаю что Вы пытаетесь сделать, но возможно поможет (См. часть до NAT): https://www.opennet.ru/tips/2683_linux_namespace_gateway_virtual_route_iproute.shtml